# Android - Pass an intent from one activity to another that implements a callback class with Firebase

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, callback, firebase-realtime-database

I have two activities: `AddUser` and `ToDo`. `ToDo` implements a class with callback. `ToDo` allows the user to create a to do list, and the to do items will be displayed instantly in a recyclerView. User can add, update, or delete to do items in `ToDo`.

AddUser.java

```
public class AddUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private DatabaseReference mUserRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);

mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

EditText etUserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserid);
EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void addUser(UserDetails userDetails){
userPushKey = mUserRef.push().getKey();
mUserRef.child(userPushKey).setValue(userDetails);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
if(v == btnNext){
String inputUserid = etUserid.getText().toString();
String inputUsername = etUsername.getText().toString();

addUser(new UserDetails(inputUserid, inputUsername));

Intent intent = new Intent(AddUser.this,ToDo.class);
intent.putExtra("userKeyRef", userPushKey);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
}
```

ToDo.java

```
public class ToDo extends AppCompatActivity implements UserTodoAdapter.Callback {

private UserTodoAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protcted void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

mAdapter = new UserTodoAdapter(this);
RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
view.setHasFixedSize(true);
view.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onEdit(final UserTodo userTodo){
// some functions here
}
}
```

UserTodoAdapter.java

```
public class UserTodoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserTodoAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<UserTodo> mUserTodo;
private Callback mCallback;
private DatabaseReference mUserTodoRef;

public UserTodoAdapter(Callback callback) {
mCallback = callback;
mUserTodo = new ArrayList<>();

// need to get the push key from AddUser activity
mUserTodoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child(users).child("Need the push key here").child("todo");
mUserTodoRef.addChildEventListener(new TodoChildEventListener());
}

private class TodoChildEventListener implements ChildEventListener{
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
        // action here
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
        // action here
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        // action here
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
        // action here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){
        // action here
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.a_custom_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
    final UserTodo userTodo = mUserTodo.get(position);
    holder.mTodoTitle.setText(userTodo.getTodoTitle());
    holder.mTodoDesc.setText(userTodo.gerTodoDesc());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.onEdit(userTodo);
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            removeTodo(mUserTodo.get(position));
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return mUserTodo.size();
}

public interface Callback{
    public void onEdit(UserTodo userTodo);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView mTodoTitle;
    private TextView mTodoDesc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mTodoTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle);
        mTodoDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoDesc);
    }
}

public void addTodo(UserTodo userTodo){
    mUserTodoRef.push().setValue(userTodo);
}

public void updateTodo(UserTodo userTodo, String newTodoTitle, String newTodoDesc){
    userTodo.setTodoTitle(newTodoTitle);
    userTodo.setTodoDesc(newTodoDesc);
    mUserTodoRef.child(userTodo.getTodoKey()).setValue(userTodo);
}

public void removeTodo(UserTodo userTodo){
    mUserTodoRef.child(userTodo.getTodoKey()).removeValue();
}
}
```

After the user clicked on Next button in `AddUser` activity, the user data is straightly added to Firebase, and the user will be redirected to `ToDo` page where the user can add to do items. How to pass the push key created in `AddUser`, so that when the user add the to do items, the items will be added under the user?

Is using intent the right way?

Please don't ask me why I need to let user add to do list right after the user is created. It's needed this way.

Thanks

Edit: I'm sorry I should mention that the intent should be passed to `UserTodoAdapter` class, so that in the Firebase database reference of `UserTodoAdapter`, I can point the reference to the key passed from `AddUser`.

I have classes `UserDetails` and `UserTodo`, for activities `AddUser` and `ToDo` respectively to handle data in Firebase.

Eventually the data will look like this:

```
{
  "users":{
    "push_id":{
        "userid":"123456",
        "username":"My User",
        "todo_s":{
            "push_id":{
                "todo1":"Title1",
                "todo_desc":"Description"
            },
            "push_id":{
                "todo2":"Title2",
                "todo_desc":"Description"
            },
        }
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing via intent (from `AddUser` to `ToDo`) is fine. Or you can save it to local storage like `SharedPreferences` so your user doesn't have to create new user if the user has created a new user.

To pass the key value from your `ToDo` activity to the adapter, modify the adapter's constructor to accept a key parameter

```
public UserTodoAdapter(Callback callback, String key) {
    mCallback = callback;
    mUserTodo = new ArrayList<>();
    mUserTodoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child(users).child(key).child("todo");
}
```

And in the `ToDo`, instantiate the adapter by passing the string extra from the previous activity (`AddUser`).

```
mAdapter = new UserTodoAdapter(this, getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to pass the value from `AddUser` to `UserTodoAdapter`?

Comment: that can't be done directly because `UserTodoAdapter` is declared in another activity which is `ToDo` unless the `UserTodoAdapter` is declared in the AddUser

Comment: Yeah I know. That's why I can't figure out how to pass the value I want to `UserTodoAdapter`.

Comment: doesn't you already pass the `userPushKey` to the `ToDo` activity via intent? then you can just instantiate the `UserToDoAdapter` by calling `mAdapter = new UserTodoAdapter(this, getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));` instead of `mAdapter = new UserTodoAdapter(this);` to pass the push key value. make sure you add the constructor in the adapter from my answer.

Comment: I'm in Java and Android era chatroom. Do you mind to discuss there?